# C / CUDA implementation with external variables produces linker error (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c, visual-c++, cuda

I have a C-Project, which I would like to boost using a CUDA-module. But somehow, the externally defined variables can not be resolved. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and CUDA Toolkit 5.0.

The following shows my minimal (not) working example:

main.c:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_test.cu"

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    testfunc();
    return 1;
}
```

main.h:

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

extern float PI;

#endif
```

testfile.c:

```
#include "main.h"

float PI = 3;
```

cuda_test.cu:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void testfunc()
{
    printf("Hello from cudafile: %E", PI);
}
```

This yields the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cuda_min, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cuda_test.cu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "float PI" (?PI@@3MA)
1>D:\Backup\diplomarbeit\cuda_xanthos\cuda_min\Debug\cuda_min.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When passing the variable PI to the function testfunc, I get the desired behavior. This is what I am doing in my project (which actually uses the CUDA-device), but I really do not want to pass about 20 variables to my functions.

I suppose I am missing some setting for nvcc...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this does not matter to the error, but your naming is strange.  If the extern is defined in `testfile.c` then it should be defined in `testfile.h` not `main.h` by convention.

Comment: You mean I should declare it in `testfile.h`? But this way I would have to include that file from **every** file in which I want to use that global variable. With my way I only have to include one file where all my global variables are declared (not called `main` ;) ), but are free to define them wherever I want. Or am I missing s.th? However, when adding a CUDA module, i HAVE TO access my global variables from that module, which by now, I cannot.

Comment: Ok, seems no one else has got any clue. Semms I have to use that dirty workaround. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: **Yes** that is what I meant. And **YES** that **IS** the way you should do it. And **YES** using globals is a pain.  And **YES** you should not use them if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, I try to keep that in mind. Unfortunateley, this has indeed nothing to do with the problem at hand. So let's assume I declared and defined the variable in `main.h` and `main.c` respectively, the linker-error persits

Answer (score 1):

`.cu` is compiled and linked as `.cpp`, not `.c`. So, you can either rename your `.c` files to `.cpp`, or use `extern "C"` in your `.cu` file.

Comment: Yes, I have heard of this, and therefore my functions, which I have dumped in the `.cu` file and which I am calling from outside this file, do have this extension. But that's not the problem. I still cannot access global variables declared and defined outside the `.cu` file from within it.